# A shorter phrase for "is a poor predictor of"

Tags: phrase-requests, phrasing

This is a bullet point in a presentation:

> Coronary angiography **is a poor predictor of** the hemodynamic relevance of stenosis

"is a poor predictor of" feels very round-about, but I can't think of a better way to phrase it. Is there one?

The phrase is meant in the sense of "is not a good method to decide".

Comment: I have only a vague sense of what most of those words mean, so it's likely I'm misinterpreting the context, but I think the problem may be that you're using "predict" when really you're trying to _measure_ or _assess_ something in the present. Would "is a poor measure of", "is a poor indicator of", or "is a poor test of" be any better?

Comment: _is a poor predictor of_ is a standard phrase in the jargon of science writing.  Are you addressing a lay or professional audience?

Comment: I would say stick with what you have, it's (as Useless says) pretty much the standard.

Comment: Hi Curtis, you're absolutely right! "Predictor" is used in this context in my field and all of your suggestions have the same meaning. I'm looking for a shorter way to express it.

Comment: @Useless Thanks, I should have mentioned the audience. They're scientists from a related field.

Comment: @Zanahoria: I don't understand what you want here. You've been told *poor predictor of * is standard phrasing in this context, and if you have some objection to that you've already used the expression *only weakly related* in a comment. How much shorter do do expect some alternative to be?

Comment: In that case, it will probably be easier for your audience to parse the standard phrase they're already familiar with, than any substitute you find (even if the replacement is shorter or otherwise better).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Maybe there were a verb that I hadn't thought of or some other clever rephrasing. I wasn't told that "is a poor predictor of" was a standard phrasing until after I had asked the question, so I don't really understand what you mean? Do you want me to delete the question?

Comment: Zanahoria: I'm not sure you're *allowed* to delete a question which has upvoted answers. But you can hardly ignore the fact that, as I write, the most upvoted response is @Useless's comment saying your original version is "standard". What I don't understand is why you think it's "roundabout". It seems very clear and concise to me.

Comment: While these may not be shorter, brevity is not valuable if it doesn't convey the right message. If I understand correctly, OP's saying that a angiography (an imaging process) does not predict with accuracy who will do well with stenting. It is an inadequate study for determining the success of stents; it does not correlate to good stent function, is a poor predictor, does not predict with acceptable accuracy, etc. There are options.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, I assume you are trying to say that once stenosis has been diagnosed, then the determination whether hemodynamics plays a significant role cannot be established by coronary angiography.

I would suggest:

> Coronary angiography is **an inadequate indicator of** the hemodynamic relevance of stenosis.

or

> Coronary angiography is **not germane to** the hemodynamic relevance of stenosis.

or

> Coronary angiography is **unsuitable for establishing** the hemodynamic relevance of stenosis.

None of these are shorter (less round-about in a sense), but they may be more to the point.

Answer (score 1):

"Poorly predicts" or "poorly correlates with" would work.  "Has low specificity for" would also be good.  What you have is fine for a "bullet point," but I suspect you want something more concise because of space or to keep it on a single line on a PowerPoint slide. There are probably other options.  "Variably correlates" also sounds good, and is the most accurate I suspect.

Comment: +1 for dropping "is", which leads to the unwieldiness. I think I would go for "weakly predicts" over "poorly predicts" though.

Comment: "Weakly predicts" and "poorly predicts" have different meanings, though. I would interpret the former as having statistical significance but low average or marginal effects, whereas the latter indicates a lack of statistical significance altogether.

Answer (score 0):

**'Is unrelated to'** would fill the bill.

Comment: Thanks. It isn't unrelated though, just _weakly_ related. And "is weakly related to" would be as long as "is a poor predictor of"